# Add a row to a TableView from a Detail view

Tags: iphone, tableview

So I have a tableView and a detail view.  I have an extra row in my tableView to "Add" a record.  When I click on the new button I send a nil object to my detail view which is the same that I use for editing an existing row.  I use the following code for that:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    new = NO;
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    SavedCarDetailController *detailController = [[SavedCarDetailController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SavedCarDetailController" bundle:nil];
    if(indexPath.row >= [listOfCars count]){
         NSLog(@"New Car");
         detailController.car = nil;
        new = YES;
    } else {
        new = NO;
        detailController.car = [listOfCars objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    detailController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailController animated:YES];
    [detailController release];
}
```

When I save my core data stuff I execute this in my detailController

```
 - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSError * e = nil;
    if(self.New){
        NSLog(@"New Car Saving");
        NSManagedObject * obj = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Cars" inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext];
        [obj setValue:Name.text forKey:@"name"];
        [obj setValue:Year.text forKey:@"Year"];
        [obj setValue:Notes.text forKey:@"Notes"];

    } else {
        NSLog(@"Updating exiting car");
        car.Name = Name.text;
        car.Year = Year.text;
        car.Notes = Notes.text;
}
    [managedObjectContext save:&e];
    if(e){
        NSLog(@"Error occurred, %@", e);
    }
    if(self.New){

    } else {
    //  [self.parentViewController.tableView reloadData];

    }
 }
```

Then I update my tableView with reloadData but it only updates the modified feild

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if(new){
        NSInteger row = [listOfCars count];
        NSLog(@" row  %i", row);
        NSArray *paths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0]];
        //NSArray * foo = [NSArray arrayWithArray:<#(NSArray *)array#>
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:paths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
        new = NO;
    }
    //This only works with "changed data" not new rows.
    [self.tableView reloadData];


}
```

This saves new rows to my database but the new row never appears.  The InsertRows actually coreDumps on me.  I am pretty sure I need to use the insertRowsAtIndexPaths but I have no clue where to put it so it will be executed once I have added the object to CoreData.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to insert the newly created car to the listOfCars array.

Comment: I was thinking that but the Car object is in the detail view and I don't pass it back to the parent.  Do you know how I can add that car to the listOfCars from the Detail view back to its parentView?

Comment: I would create the new car object and add it to the array in didSelectRowAtIndexPath (with some default values) and then pass it to the detail view controller.